# if statements only applying the first condition

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple blackjack game, but I have come across a problem on the last step i have created an if statement to decide if the user paying wins draws or loses, it seems to only execute the first condition in the statement when the stand button is pressed, so no matter if the user wins or loses it always displays `"you win"`.

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<title>
  Blackjack
</title>

<body>

  <head>
    <h1><i>BLACKJACK</i></h1>
    <h4>
      Computers Cards: <input type="text" id="computerscards" value="18">
      <br>Player 1 cards: <input type="text" id="playerscards">
    </h4>
  </head>

  <input type="button" value="start" onclick="document.getElementById('playerscards').value = random()">

  <input type="button" value="deal" onclick="dealcard()">

  <input type="button" value="stand" onclick="keepcards()">

  <input type="button" value="new game" onclick="window.location.reload()">

  <p>To start the game press start and draw a card<br> Press deal to add a new card <br> press stand if you do not wish to draw a new card<br> Prsee new game if you want to refresh the page to play a mew game</p>
</body>
<script src="java.js"></script>

</html>
```

**[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):**

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

function random() {
  return randomnumber;
}

var total = randomnumber;

function dealcard() {
  total += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  document.getElementById('playerscards').value = total;

  if (total > 21) {
    alert("You have gone bust click new game to play again!");
  }
}

function keepcards() {
  if (total > randomnumber) {
    alert("You win!");
  } else if (total < randomnumber) {
    alert("You lose!");
  } else if (total == randomnumber) {
    alert("It is a draw!");
  }
}

now = new Date();
localtime = now.toString();

hours = now.getHours();
mins = now.getMinutes();
secs = now.getSeconds();
document.write("<h1>");
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
document.write("</h1>");
```

Comment: You set `total` to `randomnumber`, then you add a few more random numbers between 1 and 10 to `total`, then you check if `total` is greater than `randomnumber`. What on earth do you expect?

Comment: Since you never change `random number` initialize it to some number <= 21.

Comment: Also, the start button is doing nothing at all. It's triggering a function which just returns the value of `randomnumber`. Maybe you wanted it to change the actual value of `randomnumber.`

Comment: `console.log(total, randomnumber)`